# How does the DDR clock compensation capacitor improve signal quality?

Tags: capacitor, clock, signal-integrity

I saw in some DDR3 designs that there is a capacitor between differential clock lines, for example the image below:

[image: capacitor]

In [the document this image comes from](http://www.altera.co.jp/literature/an/an520.pdf) it says:

> On the DDR3 SDRAM DIMM, there is also a compensation capacitor, CCOMP of 2.2 pF, placed between the differential memory clocks to improve signal quality

My first thought was that it adds a pole at certain frequencies (problematic ones) that dampens high frequencies disturbance.

How does adding this capacitor help?  I've seen some graphs and the positive effect it has (smooths the signals) but what is the (simple?) theory behind it?

Comment: Are you aware that the capacitor is connected to the main transmission line by two short transmission lines and given that your diagram doesn't specify anything about them it's difficult to determine whether the cap is acting like a cap or an inductor.

Comment: I am aware, I dont know their lenghts. it is more of a general design question.

Comment: I think any answer will involve a bit of speculation, that's the problem I guess. I think if you look at the graph following the picture, the cap is acting like an inductor. It appears to be pre-distorting the clock signal so that subsequenct TL capacitance makes the signal on the last SDRAM still acceptable. Without the "inductor", the clock signal on the final SDRAM might be too "out-of-shape" to be usable.

Comment: the cap' is ~1pF, and frequencies are ~1,2 Ghz, so it does adds up to an inductor. I'll go back to Transmission Line's theory books from here....thanks

Answer (score 1):

This capacitor is related to jitter compensation and improving VIX threshold..

I can give few references.

1. there is a discussion regarding this on si-list

http://www.freelists.org/post/si-list/DDR3-Clock-differential-signal-termination.

1. www.jpier.org/PIER/pier121/04.11080302.pdf‎
   "the timing jitter can be reduced by placing a capacitor to compensate for
   the velocity difference caused by different propagation modes"

Altera mentioned Ccomp should be added to increase the signal quality

For DDR, there are few app notes from micron and freescale which will demonstrate the compemsated Bus topology to improve timing margins.
TN-46-07

I didn't find any SI waveforms which will demonstrate with or without Ccomp differences.

Comment: hi, they are talking about a shunted capacitor to ground, I was talking about a capacitor placed between the differntial clock signals. (the capacitors sizes are different also, ~uF vs. ~pF)

Comment: Shunted Capacitor is mentioned in DDR app notes..it is mentioned for single ended signals.for differential signals like DDR3 Clock capacitor will be connected parallel to CK- and CK+. It mainly recommneded when loading is more. we have used them when we are using 9 x8 DDR3 chips for each DDR3 controller. AN520 from Altera is having few words on this.

Comment: Hi :) what do you mean by "when loading is more" ?

Comment: if perfect answer is required, This should be decided by simulation. We have used this Ccomp for 9 loads (x8).

Comment: I think loading more means that the fanout of the clock pin is high.

Answer (score 0):

The Ccomp acts as a high freq filter.  Since it's a differential trace, there's sort of a virtual ground that's not shown by the schematic.  It's easier when you visualize it as two Caps connected to ground in the middle. 
[image: Sort of virtual ground]

And the simulation:
[image]

Then see similar results circuit 2 and sim 2:

[image: Circuit1]
[image: Sim2]

Comment: This is a little simplistic of an answer when Transmission Theory is known by @YNWA. It is very possible that this capacitor is acting as an inductor or as part of a matching circuit that would take too much board space to do using tuning stubs. If I recall, those blue wire will be treated as "perfect wires" and ignore the transmission theory required to solve this problem.